# Dyanamic highchart with csv/txt input file

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, csv, highcharts

I am new on highchart. I have gone through the help portal of this and I am unable to fulfill my requirement so need you help/guide to complete this task .

My task is to read the data from a csv/TXT file which contains TPS details as per below format and show it on a dynamic running chart ( it's ok if the chart will refresh in one minute ) .
DATA format:
16:08:02,3
16:08:04,5
16:08:05,1
16:09:01,10

The above file is appending on every second , will read the last one minute data from file and plot this on chart .

I have tried this using below code. Don't know what I am missing.

```
    <!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
        <title>TPS Example</title>

        <script type="text/javascript" src="C:/Backup/SUNIL/Software/library/jquery-2.2.0.js"></script>
        <style type="text/css">
${demo.css}
        </style>
        <script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {
    $(document).ready(function () {
        Highcharts.setOptions({
            global: {
                useUTC: false
            }
        });

        $('#container').highcharts({
            chart: {
                renderTo: 'container',
                type: 'spline',
                animation: Highcharts.svg, // don't animate in old IE
                marginRight: 10,
                events: {
                    load: function () {

                        // set up the updating of the chart each second
                        var series = this.series[0];
                        setInterval(function () {
                            var x = (new Date()).getTime(), // current time
                                y = Math.random();
                            series.addPoint([x, y], true, true);
                        }, 1000);
                    }
                }
            },
            title: {
                text: 'TPS Data'
            },
            xAxis: {
                type: 'datetime',
                tickPixelInterval: 150
            },
            yAxis: {
                title: {
                    text: 'Value'
                },
                plotLines: [{
                    value: 3,
                    width: 1,
                    color: '#808080'
                }]
            },
            tooltip: {
                formatter: function () {
                    return '<b>' + this.series.name + '</b><br/>' +
                        Highcharts.dateFormat('%H:%M:%S', this.x) + '<br/>' +
                        Highcharts.numberFormat(this.y, 2);
                }
            },
            legend: {
                enabled: false
            },
            exporting: {
                enabled: false
            },


         series: [{
                name: 'Random data',
                data: (function () {
                    // generate an array of random data
                    var data = [],
                        time = (new Date()).getTime(),
                        i;

                    for (i = -19; i <= 0; i += 1) {
                        data.push({
                            x: time + i * 1000,
                            y: Math.random()
                        });
                    }
                    return data;
                }())
          }]
        });
    });
});
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
<script src="C:\Backup\SUNIL\Software\library\Highcharts-4.2.1\js\highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="C:\Backup\SUNIL\Software\library\Highcharts-4.2.1\js\highcharts.js"></script>

<div id="container" style="min-width: 50px;  height: 200px; margin: 0 auto"></div>

    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You should not load highcharts twice, please ensure if your paths are correct and move script to the head.

Comment: HI have tested one sample case that was working fine ,even i removed the duplicate line as well . it's not working , i have added below code as well . $.get('data.csv', function(data) {
            var lines = data.split('\n');
            $.each(lines, function(lineNo, line) {
                var items = line.split(',');
                c.push(items[0]);
                d.push(parseInt(items[1]));
            });
        });

Comment: To working with ajax, you need to use webserver, because browsers block load files from local system.

Answer (score 0):

You probably have incorrect paths to your script files.

```
<script src="C:\Backup\SUNIL\Software\library\Highcharts-4.2.1\js\highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="C:\Backup\SUNIL\Software\library\Highcharts-4.2.1\js\highcharts.js"></script>
```

The code works fine: http://jsfiddle.net/tmp3pty2/